# SQL creating a query help. This is what I have and I am not getting the correct output

Tags: sql, oracle, output, sqlplus

Question: Find the name and address of all people (without duplicates) who are a primary owner of at least three SUVs.

My answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, addr, type
  FROM owner x, owner y, owner z, people p, vehicle_type
 WHERE x.owner_id = y.owner_id AND x.owner_id = z.owner_id AND type='SUV';
```

This answer does not give me the correct output.  here are the tables I used:

```
people( sin, name, height,weight,eyecolor, haircolor,addr,gender,birthday )
owner(owner_id, vehicle_id, is_primary_owner)
vehicle_type( type_id, type )
```

where type_id is a number and type is SUV/SEDAN/truck or whatever other type of car you can think of.

I am using SQLplus

Comment: Can you use `ROW_NUMBER()` function in Sqlplus ???

Comment: Something is missing. What is relation between `vehicle_type` and `vehicle`?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this query with join and aggregation:

```
select p.name, p.addr
from owner o join
     people p
     on p.owner_id = p.people_id join
     vehicle v
     on o.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id and v.type = 'SUV' and o.is_primary_owner = 1
group by p.name, p.addr
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Some comments.

1. Learn proper join syntax.  It makes queries much easier to read.
2. When using table aliases, use abbreviations for the tables, so you can tell where the columns are coming from (i.e., in your query, `o1`, `o2`, and `o3` are more sensible than `x`, y`, and`z`).
3. You don't need `type` in the `select` list because you are specifically looking for SUVs.  If you want it, just as `'SUV' as type`.
4. I have no idea what the real field is in `people` for joining the tables.  I'm guessing it is `people_id`.  It might be `sin`.
5. I am guessing that `is_primary_owner` takes on a value of 0/1 for false/true.  Set it according if the values are different.

Comment: i am sorry i was not clear/  you answer is good, but I did not include enough information for you to answer it correctly.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT name, addr from owner x,vehicle type t where is_primary_owner = true and type='suv';

this maybe works only for who have almost one suv.